# View.OnClickListener not switching to another activity

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-view

Been trying to create a food delivery application as a project for colleege and the View.OnClickListener is greyed out in Android Studio and as a result, the switch between activities doesn't seem to work at all.

Excerpt from **MainAdapter.java**

```
...

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.viewholder> {

    ArrayList<MainModel> list ;
    Context context;

    public MainAdapter(ArrayList<MainModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_mainfood , parent , false);
        return new viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position) {

        final MainModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.foodimage.setImageResource(model.getImage());
        holder.mainName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", model.getImage());
                intent.putExtra("price", model.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("desc", model.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        });
    }
```

Here is the complete **MainAdapter.java** file:
https://pastebin.com/F7TWa3nf

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `holder.itemView` but `itemView` is not defined in your **viewholder** class .

You can use

```
holder.foodimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", model.getImage());
                intent.putExtra("price", model.getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("desc", model.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("name", model.getName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this didn't help.

Comment: you can share screenshot of android studio

Comment: you just clean and project and rebuild

Comment: Turns out the reason it is greyed out is because it's suggesting to replace it with lambda. However doing that doesn't switch activities either.
https://imgur.com/a/IMVGQYO

Comment: Here's sample_mainfood.xml:
https://pastebin.com/9gqPfVBu

Comment: No, unfortunately.